# How to put Fortify Enchanting on gear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I swear I've put Fortify Enchanting on gear before, but people are saying it doesn't exist, I've been playing Skyrim for many years.

I swear I've done it before because I always made a set of 4 for Enchanting, Alchemy, and Smithing. If one is absolutely certain they have done it before, how exactly can it not exist?

Comment: This sounds more like a rant rather than a question

Comment: You can probably find a guide to the enchanting loop from 2011ish that specifically mentions how there's no fortify enchanting enchantment.

Comment: We cannot really answer the question how something that you are sure of exists actually doesn't. I take it my title edit is the question you ultimately wanted to ask?

Answer (score 2):

Fortify Enchanting only exists in potion form just like fortify Alchemy only exists in the form of enchants.

However, wearing [Ahzidal's Armor](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Ahzidal%27s_Armor) does increase your enchanting by 10 points.

You probably used a mod that allowed for armor to be enchanted with Fortify enchanting but it does NOT exist in the base game.

When it comes to Crafting gear the best set-up would be:

- Head: Alchemy & Alteration
- Chest: Alteration & Smithing
- Hands: Alchemy & Smithing
- Necklace: Alchemy & Smithing
- Ring: Alchemy & Smithing

The reason i suggest adding Alteration is for the Transmute Ore spell to turn iron in to silver/gold to craft rings.